# How to solve coreData error in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Actually I have some experience in coreData with iOS 10.
But I now create an app thats tartget is #version 8.0 and above.
First I create an app including coreData. So they auto generate me a code in AppDelegate as iOS 10 standard. When I change the target 10 to 8.0 the AppDelegate shows some errors.

## Error in AppDelegate

[image]

How to solve this? I want to use coreData in ios 8.0 and above.

```
 // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "coreDataTestForPreOS")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                 
                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}

let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
} else {
    // iOS 9.0 and below - however you were previously handling it
    guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension:"momd") else {
        fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
    }
    guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
        fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
    }
    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
    context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
    let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
    do {
        try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
    }

}`
```

Comment: where I write? Can you edit my code posted above and repost

Comment: in saveContext() ?

Answer (score 1):

Before the convenience of `NSPersistentContainer` there was `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. You'll need to create one of those:

```
    if 
      let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "momd"),
      let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL),
      let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model) {
          ...
    }
```

and then create and add one or more `NSPersistentStore`s to it via `.addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options)`.

Comment: in where? I don't understand. I am beginner to iOS not expert please explain briefly where I add and How it work.